# Jquery add text to a new appended element

Tags: jquery, text, append

I know I can do this

```
  $('.intro').append('<p>this is my text</p>');
```

but how can I text to the new element by chaining it

```
  $('.intro').append('<p></p>').text('this is my text');
```

Comment: The `.append` function returns the original element, not the appended one... check my answer below :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.append()` call returns the element that run it (the `.intro` element in your code), and not the appended element (`p` in your code).
If you want you can separate the creation the appending of the `p` element like so:

```js
var $p = $('<p />').append('your text goes here');   
    // and then you can: 
    $('.intro').append($p); // this returns the '.intro' element
    // or
    $p.appendTo($('.intro')); // this returns the $p element...
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the two:

```js
$('.intro1').append($('<p/>').text('this is my text'));

$('.intro2').append('<p></p>').find('p:last-child').text('this is my text');
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro1"></div>
<div class="intro2"></div>
```

The problem is that the `append` returns the parent element (and not the one you just added).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let me help
If you have to append and attach a text to id, do it like this

```js
$("<p> Hello this is a text</p>").appendTo($("#item"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="item">Append now</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

**It should work like you want!** **:)**

```
$('.intro').append('<p></p>').find('p:last').text('this is my text');
```

You also miss a single quote there.

### UPDATE

This is more correct where jQuery will wait till append() is really done 100%:

*note: the above method is work, but harsh*

```
$('.intro').append('<p></p>').promise().done(function() {
    $(this).find('p:last').text('this is my text');
});
```

Comment: The usage of `.find()` to find the element you've just created is not recommended (performance-wise). It's better to keep your code DRY, and avoid redundant functions calling when possible.

Comment: yeah maybe you're right, but I'm here just answering the question :')